# R dataframe attributes not loading

Tags: r, dataframe, attributes

I downloaded a R dataframe from a website to access a database posted online, but when I open the dataframe in R, all the values load fine, but none of the attributes seem to load (e.g. factor levels and variable names). Is there some way to fix this?

There are quite a lot of variables, so only used the first 5.

```
> str(WVS[,1:5])
'data.frame':   90350 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1 : int  6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ V2 : int  12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ V2A: int  12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 ...
 $ V3 : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ V4 : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> head(WVS[,1:5])
  V1 V2 V2A V3 V4
1  6 12  12  1  1
2  6 12  12  2  1
3  6 12  12  3  1
4  6 12  12  4  1
5  6 12  12  5  1
6  6 12  12  6  1
```

Comment: Please show `str(x)` and `head(x)` to show what you mean.

Comment: So V2-V4 are supposed to be factors with different levels.

Comment: What was the import protocol? Did you use `read.table` or perhaps `load` from a .RData file? Perhaps you could show the source of what the input should look like? Ideally we would get a reproducible example...

Comment: but when I try levels(V2) it returns NULL.

Comment: Just load from .rdata file. When I run str() on the whole dataset there are value labels specified at the end, but I can't seem to access what these all are.

Comment: Then they are probably attached as attributes. You will have to change variable values by hand, unfortunately.

Comment: Show us what those attributes look like? The variables are numeric, why do you expect them to have `levels`?

Comment: Yes, I saw that now. I;ve actually managed to find the issue. It was in how the original authors exported the data from SPSS. Luckily I could get their original SPSS file and then did a more suitable export which solved the issue. Doing the recoding by hand would have been a nightmare as the values are country names and over 80k cases!

Answer (score 0):

If you are **loading the data from a file(eg. csv file)** and the variable names are not loading then please refer to this:

data <- read.csv("path.to.file",header = TRUE)

Though by default the 'header' is true but still you can try if this works.

Also if the values of these **variables are of datatype String** (character), and you don't want it to be considered as 'factors' in R don't forget to add this:

data <- read.csv("path.to.file",header = TRUE,**stringsAsFactors = FALSE**)

If you are reading from some other file format please resend the query with more information.